# Как правильно обойти объект JS для построения дерева?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

есть массив:

```js
[
     {
        id: 12,
        obl: { id: 8, name: 'Название области', parent: null},
        org: {id: 9, name: 'Название организаций', parent_obl: 8},
        podr: {id: 8, name: 'Название Подразделение ', parent_org: 9},
        dolzh: {id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
        count: 4354
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        obl: { id: 5, name: 'Название области', parent: null},
        org: {id: 6, name: 'Название организаций', parent_obl: 5},
        podr: {id: 7, name: 'Название Подразделение ', parent_org: 6},
        dolzh: {id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
        count: 4354
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        obl: { id: 8, name: 'Название области', parent: null},
        org: {id: 9, name: 'Название организаций', parent_obl: 8},
        podr: {id: 8, name: 'Название Подразделение ', parent_org: 9},
        dolzh: {id: 11, name: 'Администратор'},
        count: 43
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        obl: { id: 11, name: 'Название области', parent: null},
        org: {id: 12, name: 'Название организаций', parent_obl: 11},
        podr: {id: 13, name: 'Название Подразделение ', parent_org: 12},
        dolzh: {id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
        count: 4354
    }
]
```

> Поле "parent, parent_obl, parent_org"  можем отредактировать как хотим...

пользователь выбирает фильтре: области[obl] и по организацию[org] и подразделение[podr]
selectedKey: ['obl', 'org', 'podr']

и результат должно выйти так. как правильно написать функцию:

```js
[

    {
        obl: { id: 8, name: 'Название области'},
        dolzh: [
            { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
            { id: 10, name: 'Администратор'},
        ]
        count: 2,
        children: [
            {
                org: { id: 9, name: 'Название  организаций'},
                dolzh: [
                  { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
                  ]
                 count: 1,
                children: [
                    {
                        podr: {id: 8, name: 'Название Подразделение'},
                        dolzh: [
                           { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
                        ]
                        count: 1,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                org: { id: 9, name: 'Название  организаций 2'},
                        dolzh: [
                           {id: 11, name: 'Администратор'},
                        ]
                        count: 1,
                        children: [
                    {
                        podr: {id: 8, name: 'Название Подразделение'},
                        dolzh: [
                           { id: 11, name: 'Администратор'},
                        ]
                        count: 1,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        obl: { id: 5, name: 'Название области'},
        dolzh: [
                { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
           ]
           count: 1,
           children: [
            {
                org: { id: 6, name: 'Название организаций'},
                dolzh: [
                           { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
              ]
                count: 1,
                children: [
                    {
                        podr: {id: 7, name: 'Название Подразделение'},
                        dolzh: [
                           { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
                        ]
                   count: 1,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        obl: { id: 11, name: 'Название области'},
        dolzh: [
              { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
         ]
        count: 1,
        children: [
            {
                org: { id: 12, name: 'Название организаций'},
                dolzh: [
                           { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
                        ]
                count: 1,
                children: [
                    {
                        podr: {id: 12, name: 'Название Подразделение'},
                       dolzh: [
                           { id: 10, name: 'Программист'},
                        ]
                   count: 1,
                        children: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

почему поля dolzh и count продублировано? потому что пользователи могут выбрать только "obl"
selectedKey: [ 'org' ]

и тогда результат:

```
[
    {
        org: { id: 9, name: 'Название  организаций'}, 
        dolzh: [
                   { id: 11, name: 'Администратор'},
                ]
        count: 1,
        children: [
            {
                podr: {id: 8, name: 'Название Подразделение'},
                dolzh: [
                   { id: 11, name: 'Администратор'},
                ]
                count: 1,
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Вам нужно использовать структуру "дерево". В корне пусто. Потомки корня элементы с parentID=null. Далее добавляете элементы в дерево. Вот приме рhttps://code.tutsplus.com/ru/articles/data-structures-with-javascript-tree--cms-23393

Answer (score 2):

на данный вопрос уже ответили на другом портале.

надеюсь не забанит за ссылку

ответ от https://toster.ru/user/0xD34F

```
const createTree = data => {

    const
        obl = {},
        org = {},
        podr = {};

    data.forEach(n => {
        obl[n.obl.id] = { ...n.obl, children: [] };
        org[n.org.id] = { ...n.org, children: [] };
        podr[n.podr.id] = { ...n.podr, children: [] };
    });
    data.forEach(n => podr[n.podr.id].children.push({ ...n.dolzh }));
    Object.values(org).forEach(n => obl[n.parent_obl].children.push(n));
    Object.values(podr).forEach(n => org[n.parent_org].children.push(n));

    this.arr = Object.values(obl);
    console.log('dddddddd', this.arr)
}
const tree = createTree(arr);
```

Comment: Не забанят. Но лучше основное (или весь ответ) перенести сюда и оставить ссылку на источник.

Comment: ок, спасибо вам